# How to get a sub-string between to characters?

Tags: php

My string is `teamsnap.dev/Hello/dashboard`. I want to retrieve sub string between two `/` tags. How can I do this?
I want Hello as an output.

Comment: split using explode and get the array then fetch which one you wants.

Comment: `explode('/', 'teamsnap.dev/Hello/dashboard')[1]`

Comment: $temp = explode('/', 'teamsnap.dev/Hello/dashboard');
echo $temp[1];

Answer (score 1):

### The explode() function breaks a string into an array.

```
<?php
  $str = "dev/Hello/dashboard";
  print_r (explode("/",$str));
?>
```

Comment: print_r (explode("/",$str)[1]); //according to question

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply by using explode function like:

```
<?php 
   $str = 'teamsnap.dev/Hello/dashboard';
   echo explode('/', $str)[1];
?>
```

It will give you the "hello" in output